# better way to show/hide div element after click on input field

Tags: jquery, html

I have two input field like this

```
<input type="text" class="span3" id name="name" >
<input type="text" class="span3" id name="phone" >

<div class="show-example1">
      show content 1
</div>
<div class="show-example2">
      show content 2
</div>
```

I want to show only div element "show-example1"  after click on input field "name"

and show only div element "show-example2" after click on input field "phone"

For this i made two div element associated with each input field.

Below is my script for performing above action

```
 $('.show-example1').hide();
  $('.show-example2').hide();

$("input[name='name']").bind("click", function(event){

            $('.show-example2').hide();
            $('.show-example1').show(400);
            return false;

        }); 

    $("input[name='phone']").bind("click", function(event){

            $('.show-example1').hide();
            $('.show-example2').show(400);
            return false;

        });
```

My script is working fine but i just want to know a better way to do above action.

Comment: what is problem with this script? or Why you think this is not better?

Comment: @SunilChavan Just take a case of 10 input field , in that case i have to add 10 events for each input and in each event i have to hide 9 div element.It increase the length of script, so i think that there may be another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. In short - I utilize tag attributes, `focus` and `blur` events to take care of this task.
The benefit of it, compared to others, is that you with few lines of jQuery you can cover all your form elements, without necessity to manually switch every other div on/off, while at the same time keeping the unobtrusive approach of you JS.

HTML

```
<form>
    Other information <textarea name="other_information" class="hintable" hint-class="show-example1"></textarea><br />
    Nationality <textarea name="nationality" class="hintable" hint-class="show-example2"></textarea><br />
    <div class="example show-example1">
        Example 1
    </div>
    <div class="example show-example2">
        Example 2
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.example
{
    display: none;
}​
```

JS

```
$('.hintable').focus(function() {
   $('.example').hide();
   $("."+$(this).attr('hint-class')).show();
});

$('.hintable').blur(function() {
   $('.example').hide();
});
```

​

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Trogvar/8vhmF/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is pretty straightforward. If I were you, I would cache the selectors for performance reasons:

```
var showExample1 = $('.show-example1');
var showExample2 = $('.show-example2');
```

And then go and use them accordingly in your code, using fast id selectors rather than slow input/name selectors:

```
$("#phone").bind("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   showExample1.hide();
   showExample2.show(400);
});
```

And so on. You could also bind the click event into a single one to minimize the code and have better readability:

```
$("#name, #phone").bind('click.toggle', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).prop('id') == 'name') {
     showExample1.hide();
     showExample2.show(400);
  } else {
     showExample2.hide();
     showExample1.show(400);
  }
});
```

The namespace on the click binder ('.toggle') helps if you want to unbind it at a later point.

**IF** you wanted to have really DRY code, you could try something like this:

```
var togglers = {phone: 'show-example1', name: 'show-example2'};
$.each(togglers, function(toggler, toggled) {
   $('#' + toggler).on('focus', function(e) { // if you call focus, also selecting the input via keyboard will work
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.' + toggled).show(400).siblings().hide(); // hiding all the elements on the same DOM level instead of just one
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing .on('click', function(event){ instead of bind.  [Here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/04/jquery-dont-use-bind-and-dont-use-live.html) is a page explaining a little bit about that.

It looks like you are trying to make  [jQuery accordions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). Check out that link.